# How change date on the fly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My output from a procedure is like

```
Jan  1 1900 10:30PM
Jan  1 1900 10:45PM
Jan  1 1900 11:00PM
Jan  1 1900 11:30PM
Jan  1 1900 11:45PM
Jan  2 1900 12:00AM
Jan  2 1900 12:15AM
Jan  2 1900 12:30AM
Jan  2 1900 12:45AM
Jan  2 1900  1:00AM
```

I want add current date with time and change date after 12:00AM

like this:

```
Friday,MAY,18 10:30PM
Friday,MAY,18 10:45PM
Friday,MAY,18 11:00PM
Friday,MAY,18 11:30PM
Friday,MAY,18 11:45PM
Friday,MAY,19 12:00AM
Friday,MAY,19 12:15AM
Friday,MAY,19 12:30AM
Friday,MAY,19 12:45AM
Friday,MAY,19  1:00AM
```

How to do this??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008:

```
select YourTimeCol+cast(getdate() as date)
from YourTable
```

Pre SQL Server 2008:

```
select YourTimeCol+dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
from YourTable
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70552/add-datepart)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE (Sday VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tt VALUES('Jan 1 1900 10:30PM'),('Jan 1 1900 10:45PM'),('Jan 1 1900 11:00PM'),('Jan 1 1900 11:30PM'),('Jan 1 1900 11:45PM'),('Jan 2 1900 12:00AM'),('Jan 2 1900 12:15AM'),('Jan 2 1900 12:30AM'),('Jan 2 1900 12:45AM'),('Jan 2 1900 1:00AM')

SELECT Sday,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',GETDATE())),Sday) AS resultAsDatetime,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',GETDATE())),Sday),109) AS result
FROM @tt
```

which is returning

```
Jan 1 1900 10:30PM  2012-05-18 22:30:00.000 May 18 2012 10:30:00:000PM
Jan 1 1900 10:45PM  2012-05-18 22:45:00.000 May 18 2012 10:45:00:000PM
Jan 1 1900 11:00PM  2012-05-18 23:00:00.000 May 18 2012 11:00:00:000PM
Jan 1 1900 11:30PM  2012-05-18 23:30:00.000 May 18 2012 11:30:00:000PM
Jan 1 1900 11:45PM  2012-05-18 23:45:00.000 May 18 2012 11:45:00:000PM
Jan 2 1900 12:00AM  2012-05-19 00:00:00.000 May 19 2012 12:00:00:000AM
Jan 2 1900 12:15AM  2012-05-19 00:15:00.000 May 19 2012 12:15:00:000AM
Jan 2 1900 12:30AM  2012-05-19 00:30:00.000 May 19 2012 12:30:00:000AM
Jan 2 1900 12:45AM  2012-05-19 00:45:00.000 May 19 2012 12:45:00:000AM
Jan 2 1900 1:00AM   2012-05-19 01:00:00.000 May 19 2012  1:00:00:000AM
```

obviouly you can choose the right format for the conversion of the DATETIME to a VARCHAR as documented in the CONVERT function, but I think this does not need help.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks 'eddo' that worked for me... thank you again. One more step here how to select only values that is greater than server time (currunt time).  Can we do it during insert into @tt.. (formate for the condition please).

Comment: do you mean this? `SELECT Sday,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',GETDATE())),Sday) AS resultAsDatetime, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',GETDATE())),Sday),109) AS result 
FROM @tt 
WHERE DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1900-01-01',GETDATE())),Sday)>GETDATE()`